# how to display checked conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to display input checked based on some conditions and I am getting an error

Here is what I have done so far

```
checkSomeCondition(){

   if(...)
    return true
   else 
     return false

}
render(
   return(
      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() =>{alert()}} checked={() => {this.checkSomeConditon}}>
)
)
```

I am getting checked all the time not because checkSomcondition is returning true all the time. I am getting checked even if checkSomeConditon is returning false.

Comment: I think you want `checked={this.checkSomeCondition()}`?

Comment: checked={this.checkSomeCondition} only

Comment: are you using material-ui?

Comment: If you are using material-ui, there is no 'checked' property on 'Input' component. If input is native element, you have to use 'defaultChecked' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the condition check result into it's own variable within the render method.

```
render(
   var checked = this.checkSomeCondition();
   return(
      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() =>{alert()}} checked={checked}>
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render(
const { checked }=this.props.
const attribute = checked //or call your checkSomeCondition()
? {
 checked: true 
} : {};
render (
   return(
      <Input {...attribute} type="checkbox" onClick={() =>{alert()}}>
)
)
```

Or to fix your code

```
checkSomeCondition(){

   if(...)
    return true
   else 
     return false

}
render(
   return(
      <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() =>{alert()}} checked={() => {this.checkSomeConditon()}}>
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is how you should handle checkboxes in react

1. Declare a new Boolean state variable with false
2. Define event handler function to change Boolean state variable value when checkbox is checked or unchecked
3. Assign this state Boolean variable to checked prop of input element
4. Make sure you bind the checkSomeCondition function manually in constructor or change it to arrow function
5. render syntax is incorrect in your code

You should do something like below

```
    constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state= {
               booleanChecked: false
          }
    }
    checkSomeCondition = () => {
          this.setState({
              booleanChecked: !this.state.booleanChecked
          });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.checkSomeCondition()} checked={this.state.booleanChecked}>
       )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works this way.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  checkSomeCondition(){

   if(10>2){return true}

   else 
     {return false}

}
render(){
  return (
  <input type="checkbox" onClick={() =>{alert()}} checked={this.checkSomeConditon} />
  );
}

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Hope this helps!